# dynamicLinks().onLink is not calling and dynamicLinks().getInitialLink() is calling but returning null url in react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

On clicking the dynamic link: it always calling getInitialLink But it returns a null and onLink is not working Any solution to get the initial link?

```
const handleDynamicLink = link => {
    console.log(link, 'homelink');
    // Handle dynamic link inside your own application
    if (link.url === 'https://invertase.io/offer') {
      // ...navigate to your offers screen
    }
  };
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = dynamicLinks().onLink(handleDynamicLink);
    // When the component is unmounted, remove the listener
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);
useEffect(() => {
    dynamicLinks()
      .getInitialLink()
      .then(link => {
        console.log(link, 'backgroundlink home');
        if (link.url === 'https://invertase.io/offer') {
          // ...set initial route as offers screen
        }
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: yes. can you tell what is react native version you are using???@BradStiff

Comment: I figured it out. With Android 33, you need an intent filter in the manifest.